# How to know TriggerContext's currently updated table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a database in which data will have to conditionally be duplicated towards a varying number of databases on the same server. The receiving tables will have the same name, but will only have key columns.

I wanted to put the db browsing logic inside SQLCLR and react as soon as data is updated in the source tables. Hence, I was hoping to reuse the same method for replication that would copy the key values depending on the currently updated table.

```
internal static void ReplicateToInstances()
{
    if (!IsTableWriteTriggerContextAvailable()) throw new InvalidOperationException();

    string currentlyUpdatedTable; // = SqlContext.TriggerContext.??????        

    // rest of the code, irrelevant to the current issue.
}
```

Is there a way to know which table the current `TriggerContext` instance is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *should* be obvious, but unfortunately it is not. T-SQL Triggers can use `@@PROCID` and then look up the parent object in `sys.objects`, but not so much for SQLCLR. Here is a Microsoft Connection item suggesting that this be fixed:

[A SQLCLR trigger should be given the parent object in the SQLTriggerContext](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/768358/)

And here is a somewhat work-around on a duplicate question:

[Retrieve the sqlobject that fired the trigger in clr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978478/retrieve-the-sqlobject-that-fired-the-trigger-in-clr)

The problem with that work-around (i.e. using `CONTEXT_INFO`) is that it does not work if either of the following conditions is true:

1. CONTEXT_INFO is already being used for another purpose.
2. A trigger can update a table that also has a SQLCLR trigger on it that needs to know the name of its parent object.

However, using the `sp_settriggerorder` procedure to set the order to `First` is on the right track.

I do have a fix for this that *might* work, even in nested trigger scenarios, but I just haven't had time to test it (please see **UPDATE** section below). The concept, though, is to do something along the lines of the following in the `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` Trigger (as well as setting the Trigger Order to `First`):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [SchemaName].[tr_SetTriggerInfo]
ON    [SchemaName].[TableName]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

  CREATE TABLE #TriggerInfo (TriggerObjectID INT, TriggerName sysname,
                             ParentObjectID INT, ParentName sysname, TriggerNestLevel INT);

  INSERT INTO #TriggerInfo (TriggerObjectID, TriggerName,
                            ParentObjectID, ParentName, TriggerNestLevel)
      SELECT @@PROCID,
             trggr.[name] AS [TriggerName],
             trggr.[parent_object_id] AS [ParentObjectID],
             OBJECT_NAME(trggr.[parent_object_id]) AS [ParentName],
             TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(@@PROCID, 'AFTER', 'DML') AS [TriggerNestLevel]
      FROM   sys.objects trggr
      WHERE  trggr.[object_id] = @@PROCID;
END;
GO

EXEC sp_SetTriggerOrder @TriggerName = N'[SchemaName].[tr_SetTriggerInfo]',
                        @Order = N'First',
                        @StmtType = N'DELETE';

EXEC sp_SetTriggerOrder @TriggerName = N'[SchemaName].[tr_SetTriggerInfo]',
                        @Order = N'First',
                        @StmtType = N'INSERT';

EXEC sp_SetTriggerOrder @TriggerName = N'[SchemaName].[tr_SetTriggerInfo]',
                        @Order = N'First',
                        @StmtType = N'UPDATE';
GO
```

This *should* work for the following reasons:

- A SQLCLR Trigger, using a ConnectString of `"Context Connection = true;"` can read from local temporary tables.
- Local temporary tables behave as follows in nested scenarios:

  - If a temp table already exists from a parent context, then a DML statement will see it and can interact with it, and those changes will be able to both additional nested levels as well as parent levels (a very handy feature)
  - If a temp table already exists from a parent context, AND a `CREATE TABLE` statement is executed for the same temp table name, rather than erroring it will create a *new* copy of that table and the temp table of the same name from the parent context will now be inaccessible (i.e. hidden). Meaning, if you are at level 3, then when that level finishes, the code of the trigger running in level 2 will still have the level 2 value and *not* the level 3 value.

  This is not possible with `CONTEXT_INFO`, which is why `CONTEXT_INFO` does not work for nested scenarios: level 3 will overwrite the level 2 value, so when control comes back to level 2, it now has the wrong value in `CONTEXT_INFO`. Given that we can only set a single Trigger as "First" and not control which one is "second" (unless you never have more than 3 triggers, in which case you could also make use of the "Last" position), then you cannot guarantee that the SQLCLR trigger will fire immediately after the "First" trigger, and if another trigger fires that modifies a table that has this trigger setup on it, then you have corrupted data in `CONTEXT_INFO`.

---

**UPDATE**
Actually, the above temp table solution probably won't work since the local temp table will probably disappear once the T-SQL trigger ends, which is before the SQLCLR Trigger fires. I still need to test this next week. If this is the actual behavior and the local temp won't work, then I have another idea that should work.

Comment: @Crono Not bad news if you read all that I added after you thought I was finished. I posted a solution that should certainly work. I was already planning on testing this next week before updating that other Question.

Comment: @Crono Actually, my idea might not work. Please see UPDATE section.